# How to create a local event bus on Vue 3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

how can I use the event bus on one page so that all components and the page can read and receive events there
For example, in vue 2, I created an object which, when the page was created, assigned fields with the context and I used this context in all components of the page
Example

```js
//main.js
global.context = new Object();
global.context.app = Vue;

//field assignment with context
global.context.authorization = this;
 
//using context
global.context.authorization.$emit(
  "authorizationMessage",
  this.t("Password fields didn't match")
);
```

Can I use imports to improve this approach?
In vue 3 I am getting error using

```js
global.context.authorization.$on("authorizationMessage", (msg) => {
  alert(msg);
});
```

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: global.context.authorization.$on is not a function
    at Proxy.created (Messenger.vue?1b1a:25)
    at callWithErrorHandling (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:154)
    at callWithAsyncErrorHandling (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:163)
    at callHookWithMixinAndExtends (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:6032)
    at callSyncHook (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:6018)
    at applyOptions (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:5956)
    at finishComponentSetup (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:6636)
    at setupStatefulComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:6567)
    at setupComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:6503)
    at mountComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:4206)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. There is no event bus in Vue 3. So `$on` will not work. See: https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/events-api.html#events-api
2. It is recommended that you create your event bus with external libraries, unless you want to make use of the supported parent-children event-based communication in which the child emits an event which can only be listened to by the parent. See: https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-custom-events.html#custom-events
3. To implement an event bus for your application, make sure that you are emitting (firing) the events and listening to them with the same instance of the emitter. Else, it won't work.
4. I preferred `emittery` (https://github.com/sindresorhus/emittery) for event bus with Vue js. It is robust with excellent Typescript support. I also use it on Node js via the Adonisjs framework.
5. Create a useEvent hook
   //file: composables/useEvent.ts

```
import Emittery from 'emittery';
const emitter = new Emittery();
// Export the Emittery class and its instance.
// The `emitter` instance is more important for us here
export {emitter, Emittery};
```

// Export the Emittery class and its instance
export { emitter, Emittery };

6. In any vue component listen to an event
   // file: AnyVueComponent.vue

```
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, onMounted } from 'vue';
import {emitter} from '../composables/useEvent'

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'ExampleComponent',
  components: {},
  props: {},
  setup() {
    onMounted(() => {
      emitter.on('event-name', async () => {
        // Perform actions. async...await is supported
      });
    })
    return {};
  },
});
</script>
```

7. In any vue component emit the event

```
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, onMounted } from 'vue';
import {emitter} from '../composables/useEvent'

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'ExampleComponent',
  components: {},
  props: {},
  setup() {
    void emitter.emit('event-name');
    return {};
  },
});
</script>
```

8. Note that you can import the `useEvent` hook into any non-Vue file and it will work. It is just a JS/TS file.

For the Quasar Framework:

1. Create a boot file

```bash
./node_modules/.bin/quasar new boot EventBus --format ts
```

2. // file: EventBus.ts

```
import { boot } from 'quasar/wrappers';
import Emittery from 'emittery';

const emitter = new Emittery();

export default boot(({ app }) => {
  app.config.globalProperties.$event = emitter;
});

// Export the Emittery class and its instance
export { emitter, Emittery };
```

3. Register with the `quasar.conf.js` file

```js
module.exports = configure(function(/* ctx */){
  return {
    boot: [
      ...,
      'EventBus',
    ],
  }
}
```

4. In any vue component listen to an event
   // file: AnyVueComponent.vue

```
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, onMounted } from 'vue';
import {emitter} from '../boot/EventBus'

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'ExampleComponent',
  components: {},
  props: {},
  setup() {
    onMounted(() => {
      emitter.on('event-name', async () => {
        // Perform actions. async...await is supported
      });
    })
    return {};
  },
});
</script>
```

5. In any vue component emit the event

```
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, onMounted } from 'vue';
import {emitter} from '../boot/EventBus'

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'ExampleComponent',
  components: {},
  props: {},
  setup() {
    void emitter.emit('event-name');
    return {};
  },
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 5):

Following the [Vue 3 migration guide for using `Vue` as an event bus](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/events-api.html#migration-strategy), replace that bus with an instance of `tiny-emitter`:

```js
// event-bus.js
import emitter from 'tiny-emitter/instance'

export default {
  $on: (...args) => emitter.on(...args),
  $once: (...args) => emitter.once(...args),
  $off: (...args) => emitter.off(...args),
  $emit: (...args) => emitter.emit(...args),
}
```

And use it like this:

```js
// main.js
import eventBus from './event-bus'

//...
global.context.authorization = eventBus
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-event-bus-example?file=src%2Fmain.js)